# Error: char cannot be converted to string

Tags: string, arraylist, char, palindrome

Help me understand and fix the error please.
I've commented the line in which error occurs.

import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    ArrayList<String> ar= new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        if (ar.contains(str.charAt(i)))
        ar.remove(str.charAt(i));
        else
        ar.add(str.charAt(i));//error in this line.
    }
    for(String x:ar)
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

}

I was trying to store all the characters that do not repeat into an arrayList so that i can check if the input string can be rearranged to become a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

To add a `char` to a `List` of `String` values, you'll need to convert the value.

You can use the `String.valueOf` method.

```java
ar.add(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));
```